# Python slow to start on Windows

Tags: python

I noticed my Python code always takes longer to run on Windows than it does on Mac.  Is there some way to improve this?  The Windows machine is very powerful so I don't think it's a hardware issue (36 core Xeon, 96GB RAM, SSD).  Python versions are similar, I'm running 3.7.9 on Windows 10, and 3.7.7 on MacOS Mojave.
For example, a simple print statement takes 7 times longer.  Checking the version takes 12 times longer.
I uninstalled all pip modules on Windows.

I'm trying to write some very lightweight scripts where fast runtime is important.

```
$ time python3 -c "print('hello world')"
hello world

real    0m0.030s
user    0m0.019s
sys     0m0.009s

$ time python3 --version
Python 3.7.7

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.005s
```

And on Windows 10 Powershell:

```
(Measure-Command {python -c "print('hello world')"}).TotalSeconds
0.2249363
(Measure-Command {python --version}).TotalSeconds
0.1776381
```

**Edit**:  I captured the events with SysInternals Process Monitor and it shows 11,222 events for a single invocation of `python --version`.  Wow, no wonder it takes so long!  Unfortunately this doesn't really explain it, because it shows 0.233 seconds delay between "Thread Create" and Load Image".

[image]

Comment: I've found the same startup time of many tools is much slower on windows, python is not alone git is much slower on windows (compared to a Ubuntu gnu/llinux install).

Comment: I'm curious, is it similarly slow if you us WSL?

Comment: In WSL the times are just as fast as mac.  But I need to trigger a script from a keyboard shortcut, so I don't think this would be possible in WSL.

Comment: Actually maybe that will work.  I can run it as `bash -c "python3 --version"` from CMD.  This works but it adds some overhead so this takes 0.0577 seconds (vs 0.011 from the WSL bash prompt)

Comment: Are you running 3rd party antivirus on Windows? Those usually check file hashes for integrity or do heuristic scans on-access. For really curious, try running Sysinternals' Procmon to see what Windows does on Python invoke. This will generate a huge log.

Comment: @vonPryz No third-party anti-virus.  I disabled all of Windows virus protection and that didn't make a difference.  Thanks for the ProcMon tip, I added details to the question.